# How to implement auto scroll view using corona sdk in lua programming?

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

I want to add a scroll view and it should scroll automatically (auto-scroll). Is there any way to achieve it, please share your suggestions or ideas

Thank you, Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "auto scroll" as the screen moves with the character then you should take a look at Lime
http://justaddli.me/

http://developer.anscamobile.com/forums/lime

scrollView is made more for making small windows you can drag up and down to get at other things on it.

I'm not sure if you've already found your own answer or not by now but I'm gonna answer it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua using Corona SDK, there's a piece of code here at ANSCANA Comunity:

[Corona SDK-Lua ScrollView](http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/scroll-content)

It is a scrollview code in Lua, but I want a Horizontal one, which implies that one page must be twice the size even for an Android app, which I am making ;P

Hope this help :D